# Dealing with torsional knee stress during Dance Dance Revolution

Tags: knees, knee-pain

Playing Dance Dance Revolution requires a lot of pivoting in place, and the friction between my shoes and the dancepad causes torsional stresses on my knees.

I'm not sure how one's knees fight such a stress. What can I do to strengthen my knees against torsional stress?

Answer (score 2):

The knee is a hinge joint that will never respond well to rotational forces. Gray Cook's [joint-by-joint](http://graycookmovement.com/?p=118) approach to training states that lack of stability in the knee is usually caused by lack of mobility in the ankle. Michael Boyle's [8 Essential Mobility Drills](http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/sports_body_training_performance_repair/the_essential_8_mobility_drills) suggests placing your toe four inches from a wall, keeping your heel on the floor, and rocking your ankle by touching your knee to different places on the wall.

Myself, since it's dancing, I would suspect that you need to be moving your hips as well. Maybe training your hip rotators with clam shells and reverse clam shells. But that might not be how you get a high score.